# Navigate to current location of a friend

Tags: ios, navigation

I must be missing something simple - I've located my son using iOS 8's Find my Friends app, and now I want to use Maps to navigate to that location.

How can I do that? I don't see a way to start a navigation from the Friends app, Siri always wants to navigate to my son's home address (I know where that is, thanks), and Maps doesn't seem to offer access to Friends either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tap the friend in the list, then go to More → Open in Maps. From there you can navigate normally.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I could swear that "More" button wasn't there a moment ago :)